# How to add actionlink in asp.net-mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to add actionlink to my code but. I am unable to produce proper view.

```
table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.Caption</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {

                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Click for rent this car", "IntoSaleTable")</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
        }
    </tbody>
```

As a result of above piece of code  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGkPt.jpg)

My code produces multiple actionlinks for a single row, but I need just one actionlink per a single row.

Comment: try to use cell in ActionLink

Comment: @DanielB I could not understand.ActionLink has 2 attributes.How can I use inside it?

Comment: Just google :) [Html.ActionLink](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the answer. In my case, which attribute should I use for foreach. I did not see any foreach example in the corresponding link. I am guessing, I need to put foreach statement inside actionlink. But instead of which attribute?

Comment: can u upload also yr expected results?

Comment: @DanielB You can see in the imgur link, blue part should be end of the every row not be the end of the every cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is adding the action link for each cell. You should render it only once:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.Caption</th>
            }
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                }

                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Click for rent this car", "IntoSaleTable")</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, try this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.Caption</th>
            }
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                }
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Click for rent this car", "IntoSaleTable")</td>  <!-- use row["Id"] to pass Id or somethig-->
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```